# Sphero 2 core api commands get timeout responses

Tags: sphero-api

Although I can command Sleep and Ping, other Core DID 0 commands do not work for me. 
For example CID 40h Diagnostic Level 1 gets an MRSP of 35h.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Error 35h means the state machine that processes the API commands timed out. Double-check the packet you sent, it probably starts fine but then lacks one or more bytes.

Dan